# java coding in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

The following code written in netbeans it shows error as cannot find `length()` method and invert if.im new to netbeans. please correct my code.thanks in advance.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       if(jTextField1.getText().trim().length() == 0 && jPasswordField1.getPassword().length() == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`getPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) returns `char[]` so use `.length` field

```
jPasswordField1.getPassword().length
```

---

**Also See**

- [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Comment: that method is depricated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords why it is preferred to use getPassword() instead

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jPasswordField1.getPassword().length
```

`getPassword()` returns `char[]`. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29).